# How to create Win32 GUI that looks more like 3DSMax, Unity Pro, or CryEngine 3?

Tags: winapi, user-interface, skinning, theming

Ok so im making a a win32 application in C++ and im wondering how to color the gui. I want to color it like the programs 3ds Max, Unity Pro, or CryEngine 3. In those application they have like a dark gray color to them. How can i apply the same colors to my win32 application?

My project is an OpenGL Game Engine.

Comment: Win32 is simply a subsystem on modern Windows versions. Do you use DirectX or GDI within that subsystem ... (or variants thereof)? Your question doesn't state any of that. Please improve it ...

Answer (score 1):

Those editors are done via custom drawn elements, either using the actual windows handlers to do so, or with a hardware acceleration via DirectX (Direct2D) or OpenGL.

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a short summary on owner drawn controls with WinAPI that should provided you with all the details you need. Alternatively you can use something like Qt, which makes control skinning very easy, or GTK which is what Chrome uses for its skinning.

As for doing the hardware accelerated part, it can come in two stages:

1. WinAPI suppilmented with Direct2D (instead of GDI/GDI+) or have the whole screen as a hardware blit surface and use OpenGL/Direct3D to custom draw windows controls.
2. Full hardware acceleration, for which it would require writing of everything from scratch, or the use of something like CEGUI.